# What happens to my downloads when I delete the virtual environment they're in?

Tags: python, download, virtualenv

I set up a virtual environment on my mac and downloaded some Python libraries. 
What happens to those libraries after I delete my virtual environment? 
Where are my downloads stored when I download them in my virtualenv?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to get the path of a module, use `help(modulename)` or `modulename.__path__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtualenv` doesn't cache the downloads anywhere. So it downloads the sources once, compiles and installs them and then deletes the download. If you delete the env, all installed modules are gone as well.